# angularjs: getting connection refused from mongodb query

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

First off, I'm new to angular, mongodb and nodejs. I started developing a simple API to get into a job, but now I just want to finish it for personal learning.

It stores locations with their geo coordinates, and I'm trying to query these locations based on min and max distance from the user's position. However, whenever I try this query, i get connection refused. I've been trying to make it work for some days already, but cant figure out the issue.

My location Schema is

```
var LocationSchema = new Schema({
  locationName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    Required: true
  },
  geolocation: { 
    type: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Point, default:"Point" }, 
    coordinates: [Number], 
  },
```

I'm sending the distance and user's position as parameters:

```
exports.find_all_locations_near = function (req, res) {
    const $minDistance = req.query.minDistance;
    const $maxDistance = req.query.maxDistance;
    lat = req.query.lat;
    lon = req.query.lon;
    if ($minDistance > 0) {
        Location.aggregate([
            {
                $geoNear: {
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [lat, lon] },
                    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                    minDistance: $minDistance,
                    maxDistance: $maxDistance,
                    query: { type: "public" },
                    includeLocs: "dist.location",
                    num: 5,
                    spherical: true
                }
            }
        ]).pretty(), function (err, location) {
            if (err) {
                //console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
            }
            else if (location == '')
                //res.json({ message: 'No location was found.' });
                res.json({ message: 'No location was found.' });
            else {
                res.json(location);
                res.json({ message: 'The end.' });
            }
        };
    } else {
        Location.find({}, function (err, location) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.json(location);
            res.json(req.params.minDistance);
        });
    }
}
```

Not sure where the problem is, all other querys and requests work. Something on my routes?

```
app.route('/api/places')
    .get(geolocation.find_all_locations_near);
    //.get(geolocation.list_all_locations);
```

The error I get is:

> GET http://localhost:3000/api/places?minDistance=10&maxDistance=100000000000&lat=45.2361152&lon=-66.1742988 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED  angular.min.js 100

I gladly appreacite any help to understand whats happening. In case you need more info, the github is https://github.com/supermonteiro/geolocationAPI

Comment: May be in server.js use mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/db'); Instead of mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db');

Comment: why? all other queries work.

Comment: Have you check in database that whatever the data your posting is storing in mondb or not???by using mongo shell commands

Comment: Yes the data is being stored.